# Why is my rule that reacts on event "After updating an existing user account" firing twice?

Tags: rules

I have a rule that e-mails me if a user updates a value of a field on their profile (this value is the name that is displayed for that user on the site; I e-mail changes to the names to make sure no one changes their name to something insulting, etc.)

However, the rule fires twice for a reason I don't understand.

The rule has a condition *compare data value* in which it checks to see if the account-unchanged and account variables have different values for the same field.  When I look at the rules debug log, I see that during *Reacting on event 'After updating an existing user account'*, there is a second *Reacting on event 'After updating an existing user account'* within the first, and so the rule gets triggered twice.  How can I prevent this from happening?

If it helps, here is the rule:

```
{ "rules_notify_if_user_changes_name" : {
    "LABEL" : "Notify if user changes name",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "user_update" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "account-unchanged:field-acc-displayname" ],
          "value" : [ "account:field-acc-displayname" ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "myemail@myemail.com",
          "subject" : "[account-unchanged:field-acc-displayname] changed name to [account:field-acc-displayname] (UID: [account:uid])",
          "message" : "[account-unchanged:field-acc-displayname] changed name to [account:field-acc-displayname] (UID: [account:uid])",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like some other module code is calling a `user_save` on `hook_user_update` triggering the rules event a second time.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed appears to be the case.  Follow-up question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56416/how-can-i-debug-why-user-save-is-being-called-twice

Answer (score 3):

It is a not ideal solution (meaning performance, rule still run twice) but IT WORKS!! I saw on drupal.org a patch for node module in core and did not like it. This solution need no code or patches. Only once my data is saved,  I have a lot of modules enabled, so is very difficult to know which one is causing rules trigger twice. I added a hidden "Boolean Trick field" on my contentype (should work also on user bundle) and set it default value to true, you need conditional rules module to do it, and I did the following in rules, simple but effective:

[image]

Comment: Interesting trick, merci for sharing it! But, how about replacing that boolean field condition with another condition that checks if the last update date/time is at least X seconds before the current date/time. If that would work also, you'd not need to add such trick-field (though the only remaining question would be to find an appropriate value for X).

Comment: Hi Pierre, this solution did worked for a sandbox proyect, then I found my problem and this solution did not make it to production. What you comment is posible, i'm thinking about a global variable instead of boolean field or the condition X time-value you refer to. let me give it a thought and if i come with a solution i will post it here. regards.

Comment: OK, look forward to your possible future post about it. If you do, make sure to leave a comment for me around here.

Comment: Better idea: instead of a trick-field, global-var or time-stamp, flags it’s the best solution,  you cuold play arrownd with flags and rules. This rule trick let’s you run the same rule several times having flags states the flow control, a ton of posibilities...

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to execute PHP in your rules you can do this as a condition:

`//lets see when we last changed this user
    $vnam = $account->uuid.":last_saved";
    $retVal = TRUE;
    $t_changed = variable_get($vnam,0);
    $now = time();
    variable_set($vnam,$now);
    //within 10 seconds, no second trigger
    if (($now - $t_changed) <= 10){
      $retVal = FALSE;
    }
    return $retVal;
    // done saving changed timestamp`