# How can I debug why user_save() is being called twice?

Tags: debugging

I have a site with a large number of modules (100+) installed and I have an issue with [my rules firing twice](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53413/why-is-my-rule-that-reacts-on-event-after-updating-an-existing-user-account-fi), which appears to be caused by `user_save()` being called twice.  (I was able to confirm this by adding a `dpm($account)` in `user_save()`, which is printed to the screen twice on my dev site when I log in as an authenticated user and update that user's profile.

Now I'd like to find which contrib module is caused `user_save()` to be called twice (of course this assumes it is a contrib module). I'm not a developer so I'm getting stuck.  I have Netbeans set up with Xdebug and I set a breakpoint on `user_save()`.  Then I started the debugger and logged in and updated a user account, but when I look at the call stack I see the following:

> /mysite/modules/user/user.module.include_once:424 
>   /mysite/includes/bootstrap.inc.drupal_load:1126
>   /mysite/sites/all/modules/contrib/devel/devel.module.devel_boot:616
>   /mysite/includes/module.inc.call_user_func_array:833
>   /mysite/includes/module.inc.module_invoke:833 
>   /mysite/includes/bootstrap.inc.bootstrap_invoke_all:1097
>   /mysite/includes/bootstrap.inc._drupal_bootstrap_page_header:2454 
>   /mysite/includes/bootstrap.inc.drupal_bootstrap:2214
>   /mysite/index.php.{main}:20

And then when `user_save()` is called again (in the same page load) I see exactly the same output.  If it is a contrib module that is causing `user_save()` to be called twice, how can I find out which one it is?

Comment: Adding `watchdog('debug', '<pre>' . print_r(debug_backtrace(), TRUE) . '</pre>');` into an implementation of `hook_user_insert()` and/or `hook_user_update()` might be a good start, it should give you a trace of what functions were called for each run up to `user_save()`. Analysing that should give you an idea of what's instigating the calls at least

Comment: @Clive Thanks, I was able to add the call to watchdog in `hook_user_update()`.  However, I had to enable syslog because it overloaded the watchdog reports screen; a single save of a user profile generated 685033 lines of text in the syslog file.  Is there some way to look at the file and get meaningful information, because there's no way I can read a half million lines of text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out Rules was the culprit.  I didn't realized that using the *Set a data value* action could cause user_save() to be called twice.

Comment: Thanks for putting this answer up here, this is really helpful to know!

Comment: Is there a way to set values without re-triggering your rule and resulting in the double rule call?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off devel. That shouldn't be calling anything that calls user save.

Comment: I don't think the OP is suggesting Devel's responsible, just that he's confirmed the problem by using Devel to ascertain that the function is being entered twice.

Comment: I thought we were looking at an xdebug stack which shows to me that user save is being called by something in devel_boot?

Comment: Hmm yeah it does look that way, but looking at the code Devel doesn't actually invoke a call to `user_save()` at any point. The most recent item in the stack is the `include_once` call from `drupal_load()` (about half way down the function), which is called from `devel_boot()`. There's simply no scope for a call to `user_load()` anywhere in that process as far as I can tell (not saying you're wrong given the information, just that it doesn't make sense)

Comment: I do have Devel enabled on my dev site, but the problem occurs on production as well, where Devel is turned off.