# How to prevent recursion when setting a data value for a user in rules?

Tags: rules

I have a rule that is triggered on the event **After updating an existing user account**.  The rule performs an action, **Set a data value**, that changes one of the values of the user account fields.

However, doing this causes the user account to be saved again, which triggers **After updating an existing user account** a second time.  This causes some of my other rules that are triggered after updating a user account (such as those for sending notification e-mails) to be triggered twice.

I know this **Set a data value** rule is the issue because when I disable it, the account is only sent once, and the other rules that send notifications only send a single notification.

Is there a way to avoid this (single) recursion when setting a data value with a rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an ideal solution, but I just manually coded the necessary **Set a data value** behaviors in PHP in a custom module; this prevents the other rules from being triggered twice.

Comment: Did you try the solution which I gave you ? That works fine as I tried with different kind of event "Checkout complete" where I was setting value & it worked as I have gave example..

Comment: No, your solution will not work because this problem is specific to the **After updating an existing user account** event.

Comment: It will work. You just have to add one more hidden field in profile & set a data value when your rule work. And check the same value in condition when the rules get executed...

Comment: I also need some way to unset the value then, because the rules need to be called every time the account is saved.

Comment: Why do you need to unset? You set value in that rule only which you want to be executed once & check the value in same. Other rule which has to be executed again & again won't set any value neither it will check..

Comment: Sorry, I think you have completely misunderstood the question.  I do not have a few rules that need to only be executed once.  I have many rules that need to be executed multiple times.  For example, I need an e-mail to be sent every time the user profile is updated.  However, several of these rules are getting called twice because the **After updating an existing account** event is being erroneously executed twice.  I need this to only be executed once.  I cannot use the workaround because the rules that are called by the event are not one-time rules; they need to be called every user save.

Comment: If that is the case then I have misunderstood you question. You could have guessed it long ago..Sorry :(

Comment: @RajeevK That's ok, I think this is a really tricky problem.  Thanks for making an effort.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems like a variation of the question '[Why is my rule that reacts on event "After updating an existing user account" firing twice?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/53413/39516)'. The accepted answer in that question might help to understand your issue (what's causing it) also, ie:

> some other module code is calling a `user_save` on `hook_user_update` triggering the rules event a second time.

That question also has [another answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/150216/39516) with a very interesting workaround, with an image which looks like so (a picture is worth more then 1000 words):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need [Rules Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. We can run loops in rules action as well as we can put OR, AND conditions.

So at one time you can run loop for multiple actions which can solve your problem but you will have to workaround.

**Edited texts --**

You can set a field in profile with display hidden status. Name as per your like e.g. - WORKFLOW.

Use a taxonomy vocab for this field value where you add action names which you perform. If you have multiple action which need to be performed only once then set this field to have multiple value.

When you perform some action which need to perform only once, add one more action relevant to this action & for which a term is available in vocab such as "mailsent","sms-sent" etc..

Now go to the condition and add one more condition where you have to check whether that particular field WORKFLOW doesn't have this value.

So when once your mail action is performed, it will add a value "mailsent" & next time your condition will deny proceeding this rules s it will get "mailsent" in the field value..

I hope it helps..

Comment: My issue is that running the action **Set a data value** on the user profile causes the event **After updating an existing user account** to be performed again.  How does this module help with that problem?

Comment: You can run the same action in the loop when you are performing some more action such as sending email etc..

Comment: I don't want to run the same action multiple times.  Instead, I want the event **After updating an existing user account** to only be evaluated once.

Comment: @PatrickKenny As per my understanding & experience with rules, it doesn't invoke some hook, so that other action get performed again.
You need to combine your all action at one place which ever you want to perform, or use some field as condition in other rules which you don't want to be performed if you have such field like those which you are updating again..

Comment: @PatrickKenny - I have edited my answer & added one workaround solution, which may help you.

Comment: You misunderstand my question still.  I did not ask how to ensure that one given action is performed only once; I want to prevent the **After updating an existing user account** event from being triggered a second time (as a result of using a **Set a data value** action on a user) after the first **After updating an existing user account** event is triggered on an account save.

Comment: BTW, that downvote is not from me.  I wish people would comment when they downvote.

Comment: @PatrickKenny - Ok

Comment: sorry to interrupt these comments from @PatrickKenny ... I also don't like anonymous downvotes, which is why I've searched (and found!) for a way to find out who downvoted my answers. It's based on what I think an SE-bug (or design mistake?), which to me has become a handy feature ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens So how are you finding user who has downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't worry about the fact that the Rule is triggered twice. If you activate debugging at `Workflow > Rules > Settings`, a grey box ("Rules evaluation log") appears when a Rule is run. In your case, you'll see that the same Rule is triggered two times. However, the second time the following message appears:

> Not evaluating reaction rule YOUR RULE to prevent recursion.

This proves that Rules is quite a smart module. :)

Comment: If it shows the rule is not evaluated, then it's not triggered twice.  I am aware of this feature, and it's great, but in my case the rule was actually getting evaluated twice (circumventing the feature), which is a big problem.